# Converting an id from server to UTF32Char

Tags: ios, objective-c, typeconverter

I'm receiving the value `0xe844`from my server, this is actually a typography (small icon image).

Right now I got this function to be able to read the value and display the icon but the value is hardcoded:

```
UTF32Char c = 0xe844;
NSData *utf32Data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&c length:sizeof(c)];
NSString *myIcon = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:utf32Data encoding:NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding];
```

I would like to know how can I specify the value from the server to be a UTF32Char?

Thanks,

Comment: It's more normal to use UTF-8 encoding, which is able to encode any character.  It's not clear why it's UTF-32, so can you explain?

Comment: I'm not sure UTF-8 will be able to display my image. If you can open XCode just try to use my code and see what happened (put the string inside a label), tell me if you can have the same result with UTF-8. Will be really appreciated, thanks

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned it can encode all possible characters.

Comment: Then can you write an answer with some code below? thx

Comment: Not really; there's not enough detail in your question to provide a code sample.

Comment: ? you just told me that you tried the code in XCode so you must understand what am I trying to do. I'm receiving this value from my server : 0xe844, I just try to decode it to display it inside an NSString.

Comment: I don't have access to Xcode at the moment.

Comment: @ludo: Can you clarify what character you expect to display? `U+E844` is not a valid Unicode code point.

Comment: @MartinR has I said inside my question, the character is suppose to display an icon. It is working with the code I post in my question.

Comment: @ludo: Then I do not understand your question.

Comment: @MartinR My problem is that I receive the value 0xe844 dynamically from my server and I dont know how to tell my code that it is a UTF32Char value.  For exemple I receive an int from my server I just have to do this: int myValue = (int)serverValue (I'm  trying to do the same things but with a UTF32Char value)

Comment: @ludo: Sorry, I don't get it (may be my fault). - How do you receive the value from the server? What prevents you from doing `UTF32Char c = (UTF32Char)serverValue` ?

Comment: NO impossible thats my problem actually, I got the value inside an NSMutableDictionnary with the key "menu_icon" I always get some error message if I use your method. For example: Cast from pointer to smaller type UTF32Char loses informations.

Comment: @ludo: Please show your code and the contents of the dictionary.